# Canvas animation with car moving along the path with curves in HTML5 Javascript

Tags: canvas, svg

Can anyone help me out to simulate the car animation along the curve path with speed control like accelerate and brake?

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial on [**HTML5 Rocks**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/racer/), how to build a racer like the one chrome developed some time ago.

Comment: Thanks Kilian for your reply.. I tried the link you shared but when I changed the svg points to M25,25 L25,510 C25,510 30,530 50,530 L320,530 C320,530 340,530 340,505 L340,420 C340,420 345,400 360,392 L460,352 C460,352 480,340 478,326 L478,300. It is not working properly.